# did a C++ code developed in VS 6.0 compile in VS 2015

Tags: c++, c++03

I said yes I can, so I've a code developed in VS 6.0 (compile fine) I think it uses C++03 version.

So I migrated the whole code (dependence ...) and now I start the compilation.

The problem that I see that there is errors in the syntax !!

like this class :

Node.h

```
class Node : public Network
{
    public:
    struct all_rights_tag {};

    Node();
    virtual ~Node();

    static const Node All;
    static const Node None;
    static const Node Admin;
 }
```

Node.cpp

```
.
.
const Node  Node::All( Node::all_rights_tag() );
const Node  Node::None;
const Node  Node::Admin( Node::all_rights_tag() );
.
.
```

the problem is when I compile this .cpp file, it fails telling me that the declaration of `::All` and `::Admin` is incompatible with definition in the header file.

I change the direct initialization from parentheses to braces:

```
.
.
const Node  Node::All{ Node::all_rights_tag() };
const Node  Node::None;
const Node  Node::Admin{ Node::all_rights_tag() };
.
.
```

and it works fine, my question is the direct initialization using brices was introduced in c++11 ([Direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)).

so my compiler of vs 2015 now both parentheses and braces initialization, so why it doesn't work.

and if there will be changes in the code to compile a code developed in vs 6.0 in vs 2015, it will be complicated, I thought not :p

Comment: *I think it uses C++03 version.* -- No it didn't.  Visual C++ 6.0 was never a standard-conforming compiler, not even C++ 98 standard.

Comment: Is this an example of [C++ most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)?

Comment: Terminology bug: the member declarations are in the header, their definitions are in the source file.

Comment: Code that compiles or fails to compile for a certain compiler (version) is only an indication for whether the code is correct regarding the specification or not, but not a guarantee. There are various reasons for invalid code to compile (or valid code to fail) for a certain compiler version, one might be that the wording of the specification was not clear enough or ambiguous from the compiler developer's point of view so they implemented it incorrectly, and incomplete implementation, or a bug in the implementation.

Comment: You want to initialize ``Node``s, but none of the (one) constructors shown here take a ``Node::al_rights_tag`` as argument. This is compounded with the most vexxing parse. You might prefer to fix these both and mybe do ``const Node  Node::All { Node::function_refutning_all_rights_tag() } ;`` (of which you have to write the function)

Comment: @Barmar if I understand this specification [C++ most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse) is added to VS compilers that respect C++ standardization, and from the comment of  PaulMcKenzie the Visual C++ 6.0 has no standard-confirming so that's why in that last one the initialization using () works ?!